# How to set custom Endpoint on golang aws api v2 for publishing on IoT Topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, aws-iot, aws-sdk-go

On the first version of aws sdk for go (github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go) the
`aws.Config` object has an `Endpoint` property but on the v2 the property is gone.

When using IoT dataplane to publish you need to set the endpoint.

I tried overwriting the resolver to return my custom endpoint but still failing.

Is there any example of how i should publish to a topic using v2 of the AWS API for go ?

Comment: I'm looking for this now, did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Yes. You need to set the endpoint resolver on the config object.

Comment: Take a look here https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/configuring-sdk/endpoints/

Comment: Thanks @gipsh, that works very neatly.